# How can I bind XPathNavigator.Select() to a control's DataSource?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, optimization, xpath

I'm working a .NET application which faces very high usage loads, so I'm sifting through the data methodology as performance has been an issue. It heavily relies on XML due to the repetitive and read-only nature of the queries.

Lots of reads of the same file occur in a single visit, some for single variable reads and some for binding to a datasource (the latter is the bigger challenge). I want to load once then pass on the object to other pages and functions that use it. Here's how I've been doing a DataSource bind:

In the parent file:

```
Public Property XmlDoc As XmlDocument("file.xml")
```

In the child file:

```
Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/path")

If nodes.Count > 0 Then
  myListView.DataSource = nodes
  myListView.DataBind()
Else
  myListView.Visible = False
End If
```

This code is easy to do, but I've just read [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx) that XmlDocument is very poor for performance. They recommend using XPathNavigator, which is easy for variables but I have no idea how to set it as the datasource of a control. This is my attempt:

```
Dim xDoc As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument("file.xml")
Dim xNav As XPathNavigator = xDoc.CreateNavigator()

myListView.DataSource = xNav.MysteryFunction("/path")
myListView.DataBind()
```

Unfortunately MysteryFunction() does not exist.

Can anybody help with this bit of code, or otherwise provide a highly performant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found one solution, so I thought I'd present it as a possible answer.

If you're focused on setting the DataSource of controls, then you should be using XmlDataSource. However XmlDataSource is no good, so you should run a second variable of an XPathNavigator. Here's how you can do it.

In the parent file:

```
Public Property Xds As XmlDataSource
Public Property XNav As XPathNavigator

...

Xds.DataFile = "file.xml"

XNav = Xds.GetXmlDocument().CreateNavigator
```

In the child file:

```
Master.Xds.XPath = "/path/data"
myListView.DataSource = xds.Data

Dim attribute As String = Master.XNav.SelectSingleNode("/path/var").GetAttribute("name", "")
```

**Update**

I did some performance testing, and doing read-only data binds from an XmlDocument is about 1000 times slower than using an XmlDataSource. There's a much smaller but still noticeable performance gain with instantiating the object in the parent file and referencing it in the child file.

As this looks like a good way about it, I'll accept this as the answer.